# DecideBufferSize values seem to be ignored

Tags: c++, directshow

I had the problem that when using a webcam as a source , the input sample was bigger than the size of the buffer provided by the allocator as you can see in the ASSERT statement in this code.

```
HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::Deliver(IMediaSample* sample)
{
    HRESULT hr = NO_ERROR;
    myLogger->LogDebug("In Outputpin Deliver", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    if (sample->GetActualDataLength() > 0)
    {
        IMediaSample *outsample;



        hr = m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(&outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return hr;
        }
        BYTE* sampleBuffer = NULL;
        BYTE*  newBuffer = NULL;
        long ulDataLen = sample->GetSize();
        long datalenout = outsample->GetSize(); //this is always 92160
        outsample->GetPointer(&newBuffer);
        ASSERT(datalenout >= ulDataLen); //This fails
        memcpy((void *)newBuffer, (void *)sampleBuffer, ulDataLen);


        m_pInputPin->Receive(outsample);

        outsample->Release();
        sample->Release();




    }

    return hr;
    //Forward to filter
}
```

So memcpy would definitely fails because you can't copy something into a buffer that is smaller than the data.
So I tried adjusting the buffersize in `DecideBufferSize`:

```
HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator *pAlloc, ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *pProps)
{
    myLogger->LogDebug("On DecideBufferSIze", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES    act;
    HRESULT                 hr;

    // by default we do something like this...
    pProps->cbAlign     = 1;
    pProps->cBuffers = 30;
    long buffersize = this->CurrentMediaType().lSampleSize * 3;
    pProps->cbBuffer = 10 * 10 * 1000;
    pProps->cbPrefix    = 0;

    hr = pAlloc->SetProperties(pProps, &act);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    // make sure the allocator is OK with it.
    if ((pProps->cBuffers > act.cBuffers)  ||
        (pProps->cbBuffer > act.cbBuffer) ||
        (pProps->cbAlign > act.cbAlign)) 
        return E_FAIL;

    return NOERROR;
}
```

which gets ignored. The size of the sample returned by the alocator is always 92160.

I also made sure that the DecideBufferSize method gets actually called.

**How do I set the size of the Buffer returned by Allocator->GetBuffer()?**

Comment: in `DecideBufferSize` the variable `buffersize` is a local variable that gets assigned, but is never used anywhere. It goes out of scope at the end of `DecideBufferSize` and has had no effect on any part of the code.

Comment: yes, ok. that shouldn't be there anyway. The point is that i set the buffer with 10 * 10 *1000 (100'000) which does not seem to be applied

Answer (score 3):

MSDN [states it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319040) pretty accurately:

> Typically, the derived class will honor the input pin's buffer requirements, but **it is not required to**.

Buffer size decision is a matter of negotiation. Your setting requirements does not mean they will be accepted.

> The size of the sample returned by the allocator is always 92160.
>
> How do I set the size of the Buffer returned by Allocator->GetBuffer()?

What is wrong exactly with 92160, what makes you think it's invalid? You are looking for an answer to the wrong question. If you own allocator, then you set its buffer size. If you don't own and manage it, then you have to live with the size it already has.

I gave you MSDN link [a few question ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358908/868014), and it explains why increased size buffers are sometimes valid, and even more so - they are inevitable.

Comment: The problem is that the buffer is too small. Do I have to split up the data and send it in to steps?

Comment: Your comment effectively says you have no idea what happens in the graph. And you don't post these details here to get well-grounded advice. What you should really start with, is figuring out how to obtaing information on **REAL** topology that you build, real connections, real media types and formats. This would explain the buffer sizes too, before you understand the topology you keep shooting in the dark.

Comment: I don't understand. What else should I do than split it up? Reject data?

Comment: No rejection, no splitting up. Your bugs already broke it up by the moment, you need to step back and fix earlier stuff.

Comment: i don't see where the bugs are